# Java HtmlUnit - faster javascript loading

Tags: javascript, java, htmlunit

I get some site with HtmlUnit, fill the form, click the button that redirect me to other site and get specific information. when I do it a 100 times, it takes a very long time and I think the reason is js loading on every page, so I want to speed it up.

I have two ideas how to do this:

1. I know there is a method that allows me to disable js loading, but i can't use it after click() method because it's automatically load page, and I can't use it before beacuse i need js on first page do redirect to another. Is there any way I can put this method between geting url by clicking and loading page?
2. Form generates url like somesite.com/ShowResults?id=[specific value based on input in form], js is always the same, only table on site is different depends on id value. Is there any way to load js once from this site, save it, and use it again in other sites without loading js again?

Comment: ad 1 I am also curious about how to do this